# How C++ reference works

Tags: c++, reference

After working 15 years in C++ I found that I don't understand references completely.

```c
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass() : m_nData(0)
    {
    }

    TestClass(int n) : m_nData(n)
    {
    }

    ~TestClass()
    {
        cout &lt;&lt; "destructor" &lt;&lt; endl;
    }

    void Dump()
    {
        cout &lt;&lt; "data = " &lt;&lt; m_nData &lt;&lt; "  ptr = 0x" &lt;&lt; hex &lt;&lt; this &lt;&lt; dec &lt;&lt; endl;
    }

private:
    int m_nData;
};

int main()
{
    cout &lt;&lt; "main started" &lt;&lt; endl;

    TestClass& c = TestClass();
    c.Dump();

    c = TestClass(10);
    c.Dump();

    cout &lt;&lt; "main ended" &lt;&lt; endl;

    return 0;
}

// prints:
// main started
// data = 0  ptr = 0x0012FF54
// destructor
// data = 10  ptr = 0x0012FF54
// main ended
// destructor
```

I understand from this test that `TestClass` instance is created on the stack (is this correct?) and initialized by first `TestClass` constructor. When is this instance allocated: when the `main` function is loaded or when the reference assignment is executed? When it is destroyed?

After the second reference assignment, the object address is not changed. Does this mean that the destructor and constructor are applied to the same memory area? Or is the memory deallocated (dynamically? on the stack?) and allocated again?

I know everything about stack and heap-allocated objects lifetime, their constructors and destructors, but I cannot understand what exactly happens in this program.

**Edit:**
Thanks to all. I tried to reproduce in this test some other (more complicated) program behavior. Your comments helped me to understand both my mistake and another program I am fighting with...

Fixed code is:

```c
int main()
{
    cout &lt;&lt; "main started" &lt;&lt; endl;
    TestClass t;

    TestClass& c(t);
    c.Dump();

    c = TestClass(10);
    c.Dump();

    cout &lt;&lt; "main ended" &lt;&lt; endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Note from 29.06.2022:** After latest edition by Daniel Walker this question looks like complete crap. I am not responsible for this.

Comment: This code won't compile.  You can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary.

Comment: Are there any implementations of C++ that don't put automatic objects on a stack?  If so, which ones are they?

Comment: Which compiler did you use to compile that? It shouldn't compile.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach It was not a stack on Cray: it was a linked list of "stack" frames, the source codes of some implementations of `alloca()` bear scars of compatibility with that.

Comment: It is a non-standard MSVC extension, compile with /W4 to get C4239.  There's some hokey pokey going on to make this work, looks like there's some reference swapping to safely destroy the first instance.  Can't say I really see how it works.

Comment: It's terminology nothing more. Particularly of a flavor I call "lawyerese speak". You'd find it heavily in the ISO standard as it's terminology designed to make statements that will remain true for decades to come regardless of implementation details. I may only have a few years experience but it's not something I plan to worry about ever.

Comment: @Alex: What matters in C++ is whether an object is automatically or dynamically allocated, because that determines the object's lifetime. Automatic objects die automatically at the end of the relevant scope, while the lifetime of dynamic objects is controlled by the user (and thus ends with manual deletion). Whether the memory for the variable is on the stack or the heap is not so important (in fact, you can trivially put a dynamic object on the stack if you want), and doesn't really help you to understand the language.

Comment: @Kerrek: with ordinary practical terminology you're wrong when you state that you can put a dynamic object on the stack. it is just wordplay. e.g., in-place allocation in some buffer on the stack, that's not what we ordinarily mean by dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Alf: Sure I can: `char buf[sizeof(T)]; T * pt = new (buf) T;`. It's a dynamic object whose lifetime I have to manage, and it's on the stack. Similarly I can put dynamic objects in static memory if I like. There's nothing unnatural about this. It's not "dynamic allocation", but rather an "object of dynamic storage". I think I was careful not to say "dynamic allocation", or just a "dynamic object". Allocation refers to memory, and construction to objects.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach I concede that regardless of the memory layout chosen by the compiler -- sequence of frames at monotonous addresses or not -- it is accessed in LIFO manner and should be called 'stack'. Also, Cray source code calls it so.

Comment: @Alf: It's not logically impossible.  Conceivably, an implementation could dynamically allocate memory via a behind-the-scenes call to `malloc` for each automatic object.  (Of course, I'm not for a moment suggesting that such a compiler exists, merely that it's not logically impossible.)

Comment: @Alf: Why is not standard-conforming?  The only place the standard refers to "stacks" is in the context of "stack unwinding" for exceptions, which is a convenient phrase, rather than an implementation requirement.  If, by "stack", you really just mean the general concept of each nested function call having its own scope for auto variables, then yes, it's always a stack.

Comment: @Oli: to take your example, "stack unwinding", which stack do you think it is that's being unwinded. it is the the stack of automatically allocated objects, and return addresses. you have some 50k rep points here on SO, which means you are not an utter newbie. hence you are lying when  you pretend to not know about the stack requirement, and also when you pretend to not understand that stack unwinding is unwinding of the stack.

Comment: @Alf: You're right, I know full well what is implied by "stack unwinding".  But I'm being careful to distinguish between the behaviour, and the implementation of that behaviour.  The behaviour is nested scope; one implementation of that is via a traditional stack mechanism.

Comment: @Oli: you are not "careful to distinguish between the behavior, and the implementation". on the contrary, you have conflated those. since this now has devolved to argument about your earlier argument, rather than repeated erroneous silly technical assertions, i will stop responding.

Comment: @Alex: calling this a "personal war" is an attack on my person. it is generally known as an *ad hominem* attack, an argument that attempts to convey an impression of a person, rather than relate to technical fact or logic. i cannot remember ever discussing anything with you or having anything to do with you, and I doubt that e.g. Oli will be very glad for your *ad hominem* based attempted help, if that is what it is.

Comment: @Alf: Agreed, this is going nowhere; it's merely an argument about definitions.  But to summarise, I don't believe the fact that function scoping is typically implemented via a physical stack mechanism means that all other implementations of this behaviour should also be called stacks.

Comment: Please keep comments constructive and on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code suffers from multiple problems and ultimately won't make sense. However, let's hack through it.

1) You can only bind a temporary to a *const* reference, thus extending its lifetime:

```
const TestClass & c = TestClass();
```

2) Now we can't use `dump`, because you didn't declare it `const`:

```
void Dump() const
```

3) Saying `c = TestClass()` is an assignment. However, `c` is now a reference-to-const, which cannot be assigned to, since assignment is non-constant (for obvious reasons). Let's hack around this:

```
const_cast<TestClass&>(c) = TestClass(10);
```

Now we've assigned a new value to the temporary-but-extended object `c`, and all is as it should be:

```
main started
data = 0  ptr = 0x0xbfa8219c
destructor
data = 10  ptr = 0x0xbfa8219c
main ended
destructor
```

The pointers are the same because there's only one object, namely the (temporary) one referenced by `c`. Assigning to it is a hack that's undefined behaviour in general, but we get away with it for the purpose of this demonstration.

The intermediate destructor is that of the second temporary `TestClass(10)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
TestClass& c = TestClass(); // TestClass() temporary doesn't persist beyond this expression.
c.Dump();
```

`TestClass()` creates a temporary and you cannot take the reference of it.

```
const TestClass& c = TestClass();
```

`const` qualification extends the life time of the temporary being created until the scope of the object `c`.

Answer (score 2):

```
TestClass& c = TestClass();
```

This wouldn't even compile!

Attempting to bind a temporary to non-const reference would result in compilation error.

However, you can bind a temporary to const reference:

```
{
   const TestClass& c = TestClass();
   //use c 
   //....
}//<-------- the temporary will be destroyed here.
```

In this case, the life of the temporary extends to the lifetime of the reference, i.e when the reference variable goes out of scope, the temporary will be destroyed as shown above.

Comment: This compiles in VC++ 2010 with waring C4239 (level 4).

Comment: @Alex: The [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/186yxbac(v=vs.80).aspx) clearly says : ***nonstandard extension used** : 'token' : conversion from 'type' to 'type'*..... Did you see the text in bold?

Comment: Some warnings should be treated as errors ... MCVC is very forgiving.

Answer (score 2):

1) you can't get not const reference to a temporary object

2) in the line   c = TestClass(10);   operator=(...)   is called

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to compare references to pointers... (references are usually implemented the same way in assembly generally by using the ebx register). The main difference is that reference is constant after initialization...

However, The line `const TestClass& c = TestClass();` is parallel to `const TestClass* const pc = &TestClass();` so the object will be create and destroyed on the stack, pc will still hold the same address.